# What stepper motor is this?

Tags: stepper-motor

I am so sorry,  I have to ask such a stupid question.  I got these stepper motors from a thrift shop, the owner had no idea what these are.  And these have all labels damaged. Can anyone help me figure out the name,  model, or wire codes of this. Thanks in advance It has pink,  yellow,  green,  and blue wires. Here is its image: https://ibb.co/HDm7BKj

Comment: Throw them away and buy ones from reputable suppliers with proper labels and bona fide data sheets

Comment: Name and model? Probably not. (it's possible that someone has seem them before however). But you can figure out the wire colours by trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) OP Label seems to say `... C720-02`

[image]

(2) Hmmm.... Google... **`C720-02 stepper motor`** ...

[image]

(3) Profit! (as they say on Slashdot). I have seen 95 Euros and 250 dollars US on different websites.

After step (2), I took another look at the OP's label, and I'm pretty sure I can see the `23LM` at the beginning now. Anyone else agree?

[Informative brochure:](http://cnc25.free.fr/documentation/moteurs%20pap/pap_nmb.pdf)

[image]

Also...

[image]

They all seem to have a standard wiring scheme.
Read the brochure... lots of info... stepping sequence on page 31.
Use this as a start for your own research!

[image]

Comment: +1 excellent spelunking.

Comment: I am sorry I had to change the accepted answer to yours.  Because, this actually is what I was looking for.  Thanks a lot. Once again,  all the advice I gained from here is huge for me. I definitely learnt a lot from you guys. Stay blessed everyone=) And to be honest,  this electronic exchange community is far better than stackoverflow - where people don't help this much

Answer (score 2):

Probe the **coil arrangement** out with an ohmmeter, and assuming that might be satisfactory for you, then compare the resistance and maybe inductance to catalogs of manufacturers with similar physical sizes to estimate the current and voltage requirements and likely performance. Don’t worry too much about polarity, worst case you reverse one pair to reverse direction, most likely.

Don’t push them quite that far to be on the safe side. You can find many DIY webpages on the different types of steppers and how they might be driven.

If this seems like more work than it’s worth, then you can buy some Chinese steppers or surplus steppers from eBay etc. that have proper datasheets, but it’s not something we can or should do for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I have not yet tried that, if it works I will definitely mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: If you don't know much about stepper motors, finding out the coil arrangement with a meter is an *excellent* way to learn about them.

Answer (score 0):

> I got these stepper motors from a thrift shop

OK, nothing wrong with buying 2nd hand stuff. If I went into a thrift shop and saw a coffee table I liked I might buy it but, first I'd check to see if the legs were fairly stable and there wasn't any woodworm or cracking.

If in the same thrift shop I saw some 2nd hand cups and saucers I liked the look of I might inspect them for the maker's name (in case it was anything particularly interesting) but I would always look for cracks and defects of some kind.

And now the stepper motors; I can't decipher the maker's name and wiring details and neither can I inspect them for any internal defects such as shorts or blown windings or bad bearings or poor insulation.

My concerns would also be what voltage they run at and how to decipher the wires because wire colours won't help at all. I would likely conclude that the time I would spend resolving all these issues plus, the probability that they will have faults that I can't fix AND that there is no chance of getting a free replacement for anything is monetarily more than going to Farnell or RS and buying reputable parts with a data sheet and a money back guarantee.

Why should anyone buy them?

Comment: You might buy something cheap even if it has a change of having internal damage you can't inspect. *Most* of these purchases *won't* end up having internal damage you can't inspect. You might take a chance by buying this motor if it only cost $0.50 and you needed a stepper motor this size for a one-off hobby project.

Comment: @user253751 No I wouldn't. I'd buy new parts with a guarantee and data sheets.

Comment: You must not have much spare time. If you buy a $30 part for $0.50 but it takes you an hour to figure it out, you've earned $29.50 per hour.

Comment: It wouldn't take me an hour because I wouldn't do it. It's taken 2 hours since the question was first asked and there's no solution. Do you see the problem @user253751. And there's no guarantee that you can figure out the driving voltage in any amount of time nor how reliable these things will be if they actually work.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.  I will try using ohmmeter as Spehro just said in answers.  I got them for 50 rupees, almost 0.30 dollars. I just thought I got a lucky draw.  But if it doesot work I will use standard nemas. Thanks to everyone again

Comment: Rupees eh? @Andyaka the average hourly wage in India is US$1.35. Would you spend even 6 hours to save 20 hours of wages? The more stuff you do yourself, the more money you earn!

Comment: Not everyone has it as good as us first-worldies with the ability to just buy stuff.

Comment: Yeah and if I put junk into a design I would get sued. How much; a lot.

Comment: Why would anybody buy them?  To learn about stepper motors!  Not everything is for a client with a lawyer

Comment: These days the internet is great for learning about stepper motors plus a wealth of other stuff. Why would taking one specific item apart tell you anything generically about steppers.

Comment: @Andy aka - "Why would taking one specific item apart tell you anything generically about steppers[?]" - this model is about as 'generic' as stepper motors can get.

Comment: Maybe you can say that; in that you know about stepper motors and were able to decipher the scratched label and recognise that these were pretty typical and generic devices but, for someone taking it apart and not knowing what is generic or not, the techs details wouldn’t point to anything generic about steppers.

Comment: Just like the OP (and you), I have Google.

Comment: Hey I wouldn’t use these steppers for anything. I’m pretty clear about that in case you didn’t know!